# Trying to shift a list to the right position number of times, filling the left side with the first value of the list

Tags: python-3.x

```
def right_shift(inputList, position):
    shiftedList = []
    for i in range (position):
        shiftedList.append(inputList[0])
    for i in range (len(inputList)):
        shiftedList.append(inputList[i])
    
    return shiftedList
right_shift([1,2,3,4,5,6], 3)
```

So I want it to return [1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6] but it returns nothing. Please help.

Comment: When I run your code I get ```[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]```.  To correct you need the second for loop to be ```for i in range(1, len(inputList)):```

Comment: It seems this is more like `expanding` than `shifthing` - by N-position?

Comment: You could just do `return [inputList[0]] * position + inputList[1:]`

Answer (score 0):

```
def right_shift(inputList, position):
    shiftedList=[]
    for i in range(position-1):
        shiftedList.append(inputList[0])
    inputList = shiftedList + inputList
    return inputList
c = right_shift([1,2,3,4,5,6], 3)
print(c)
```